# Is the notion of "Godhead" opposed to Vaishnavite theology?

Tags: vaishnavism, terminology

Wiki of [Godhead in Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godhead_in_Christianity) says:

> Godhead (or godhood), is the divinity or substance (ousia) of the Christian God, the substantial impersonal being of God, as opposed to the individual persons or hypostases of the Trinity; in other words, the Godhead refers to the "what" of God, and God refers to the "who" of God"

From what I understand, in vaishnavite theology, the ultimate reality is a person.

Comment: Why do you refer Christianity while talking about Vaishnavite thplogy? Term Godhead is used in different traditions with different meanings.